# Sharepoint Online Check Permissions for deleted external user

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-permissions

I have a SharePoint Online site where I want to delete certain permissions.
I use to share with external users. Now some of those users where deleted because they don't work any more on the site, but still keep viewing some weird permissions if I use the Check Permissions Option.
I see this

[image]

I see that this user has 2 Limited Access but has not information how it was given

I have tried some powershell commands but I don't see this user on results.

How the "Check Permissions" 'd get this information?

Answer (score 0):

The limited access permission level includes the minimum permissions that a user must have to access the required location. Users may have limited access if an item (library/folder/document) under the parent site (site/library/folder) has been shared with them.

SharePoint automatically assigns limited access when it’s needed. Let’s say a manager wants to give a user access to a document. The permissions that grant access to the user are added directly to the content, permission inheritance is consequently broken, and limited access then automatically gives permissions to the user at the site level.

SharePoint automatically assigns limited access to other required locations, such as the site or library in which the single item is located. It will not automatically remove the limit access from the site or library when removing the user permission from the item as it does not know whether this user has unique permissions on other items in this location.

Comment: And how could I know the source of those 2 items I see with "Limited Access". Usually it says "Granted by ...." but I do not see that information in my case

Comment: There's no way to check. If you delete the users from site collection, these users will not have permissions for the site collection, including limited access permission.